# All warnings and errors of my document refer to "forest.sty"

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, forest

I use TeXstudio and TeX Live 2016. I need the forest package for one of my figures. When I receive an error or a warning, the Log Window of TeXstudio refers to the forest.sty package and when I click on the message, the forest.sty file will be opened.

Example:
[image: Errors and warnings]

This is very impractical. Does anybody know how I can get rid of this behavior? The line number seems to be correct for the main tex file.

MWE which generates one warning refering to the forest.sty:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\resizebox*{!}{.4\textheight}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sffamily,
Dateblock/.style={
draw,
fill=white,
rectangle, 
minimum width={width("1984")+2pt},
font=\bfseries},
]
\node[Dateblock] (1964){1964};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This codes produces only an `overfull \hbox` warning quite unrelated to `forest`.

Comment: I remember this being reported before, but I just can't find it. Which version of `forest` are you using? If not the latest (2.1.4), does the error persist if you use the latest version?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with a current miktex but I don't see any unbalanced delimiter in the log, so it looks more like a texstudio bug and you should better report it there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think so. If I run this, I don't get an error, but all of the warnings are attributed to `forest.sty` by my editor. If it is an editor bug, it certainly isn't specific to either MikTeX or TeXStudio.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović It isn't so much the error. It is the attribution of all errors and warnings to `forest.sty`. If I compile the code, all warnings are from `forest.sty` according to my editor. I am not using TeXStudio or MikTeX.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović More minimal example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}` The bad box warning is attributed to Forest.

Comment: Can you share your `.log` file with us?

Comment: @cfr my editor (winedt) doesn't "attribute" warnings in this way. But imho editors that do it analyze the delimiters in the log. Which editor are you using?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I found the source of the problem, see my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Kile.

Comment: @cfr and does it have the same problem as in the example of my answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, of course. Those are always going to be spat out in the log for any document which uses Forest.

Comment: @cfr no I meant: Does the log-parser of kile get confused by a simple `\typeout{()}` too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, yes. I suspect there's a common parser thing here somewhere, although the editors are not closely related as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the log parser of TeXstudio. Will be fixed in the next release (2.12.4).

Comment: It seems to persist with 2.12.6

Comment: The above example does work for me. Please report a failing example at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/

Comment: I did just that. https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2268/ Thanks for fixing. Great software!

Answer (score 9):

The source of the problem are some messages of xparse when the "d" or "r" types are used together with parentheses. This leads to messages in the log which contain an empty parenthese pair:

```
 Defining command \test with sig. 'r()' on line 3
```

These empty parenthese pair seems to confuse texstudio.

A simple example to demonstrate the problem is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{filecontents}{parenthese-bug.sty}
    \typeout{()}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{parenthese-bug} 
\begin{document} 
\rule{40cm}{1cm} 
\end{document}
```

which leads to this output:

[image]

forest uses internally a `d()`-type declaration, but I found also other packages which triggers the same behaviour in texstudio. This is imho a bug of texstudio and you should report it.

Answer (score 1):

A similar bug affects Kile.

Reference for Kile bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=377789.

In the case of Kile, as a workaround, you can write

```
\typeout{)}
```

before `\begin{document}` and the warnings/errors will be attributed (more) correctly.

Unfortunately, it seems that this workaround will not work in TeXStudio. (Possibly distinct but related bugs are involved?)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in my case.

Comment: @Konne That's too bad. At least TeXStudio will get a fix soon, though. Much less likely in Kile.