# Texstudio jumps to wrong document when clicking on errors in Log File

Tags: errors, texstudio

When i double click on errors in the log file tab i get directed to a physics.sty latex document(no idea what this is) instead of the line in the code that causes the error. Is this supposed to happen and what can i do to make it jump to my document instead?[image]

Comment: Perhaps this bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358990/all-warnings-and-errors-of-my-document-refer-to-forest-sty.

Comment: Which version of texstudio do you use?

Comment: Version 2.12.4 fixes a bug in the log parser. Please try with a current version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a bug in TeXstudio that is already fixed.